# Comparison between a date and a date converted in char

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle Database, can you tell me why this query return `FALSE` ?

```
select 
case 
  when to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY') >= (to_date(to_char(to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY')))) then 'TRUE'
  else 'FALSE'
end
from DUAL;
```

And how can I do to have `TRUE` ?

I want to compare two identical dates, one is a `varchar2` and the other is a `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be the same, use the same format for all functions :

```
select 
case 
  when to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY') >= 
  (to_date(to_char(to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')) then 'TRUE'
  else 'FALSE'
end
from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is clear if you run:

```
select to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY'),
       to_date(to_char(to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY')))
from DUAL;
```

On SQL Fiddle, this returns:

```
January, 01 1900 00:00:00   January, 01 2000 00:00:00
```

The problem is that the default date format for Oracle uses 2-digit years:  `01-JAN-00`. You can fix this by including explicit formats at each step:

```
select to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY'),
       to_date(to_char(to_date('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
from dual;
```